# How to use DispatchGroup to make asynchronous calls within a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

In my example code below, I call `complete(false)` on failure. However, since I'm using a `DispatchGroup` object to make sure all asynchronous requests are complete, I cannot just call `syncGroup.leave()` on failure, as the `notify` will be called, which contains `complete(true)`, making this function return `true`, when it should be returning `false` for failure.

Am I correct in not calling `syncGroup.leave()` on failure to complete my function correctly? Or should I be calling `syncGroup.leave()` and somehow trying to determine what the result is, so I can return `false` on failure?

```
let syncGroup = DispatchGroup()
syncGroup.enter()
for track in unsynced {
    register(time: time, withCompletion: { (success: Bool) -> () in

        if success {
            self.debug.log(tag: "SyncController", content: "Registered")
            syncGroup.leave()
        }
        else {
            complete(false)
        }
    })
}

//all requests complete
syncGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    self.debug.log(tag: "SyncController", content: "Finished registering")
    complete(true)
}
```

Comment: Your approach is flawed since you are dispatching many tasks but only returning a single status.  You need to consider what you want to achieve; Perhaps you should either be prepared to receive multiple callbacks (perhaps passing the `track` as well as the true/false result) or call the callback once but pass an array of tracks/statuses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enter the group within your for loop. You might want to introduce an additional error flag.

Example implementation:

```
    var fail = false
    let syncGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for track in unsynced {
        syncGroup.enter()
        register(time: time, withCompletion: { (success: Bool) -> () in

            if success {
                self.debug.log(tag: "SyncController", content: "Registered")
                syncGroup.leave()
            }
            else {
                fail = true
                syncGroup.leave()
            }
        })
    }

    //all requests complete
    syncGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        if fail {
            complete(false)

        } else {
            self.debug.log(tag: "SyncController", content: "Finished registering")
            complete(true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can I exit out of that loop, instead of going through the remaining objects in `unsynced`? `break` wont work because its in a closure right?

Comment: You can not. The loop triggers your async operations. Most probably (depending on the time the task uses and the number of `unsynced`) all register tasks are triggered before the first calls it completion block. For many items in `unsynced`, you can add `if fail { break }` as first code in the `for loop`.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. While those requests are async, it might save one or two from sending a request.

Comment: To be able to cancle operations, checkout Operation & OperationQueues. It`s a OO abstraction of GDC.

Comment: Watch out! Assigning a value to a variable is not necessarily thread safe. The update of `fail` should itself be queued to avoid multiple threads trying to update it simultaneously: `DispatchQueue.main.async { flag = true }`

Comment: @JohnJ.Camilleri: imo it should be safe as its a local variable. Couleur you explain how it is not safe?

Comment: @shallowThought Well multiple threads are all trying to update the same variable `fail` at the same time, and you have no control over the low-level scheduling of those threads so in theory it could end up having an unexpected value. Admittedly this is often safe in practice when all assignments are the same (`fail = true`) but this approach could lead to problems if `fail` was a counter that was being incremented, for example.

Comment: @JohnJ.Camilleri afaics every thread has its own `fail` variable.

Comment: @shallowThought That can't make sense, if each thread had its own `fail` variable, then which one is being checked in the final `if fail` condition? That code is executed only once, not once _per thread_. Or maybe we have different ideas of threads here. I am assuming that each call of `register` is spawning a new thread, each of which is accessing the same `fail` variable. Unless you have some guarantees about the scheduling of those threads, then my point stands. Again, this is a theoretical problem which is not easy (but not impossible) to encounter in practice.

Comment: @JohnJ.Camilleri I had a second look. You are right. Will update the answer accordingly.