# Chain multiple Alamofire requests based on Array<>.count

Tags: swift, asynchronous, download, request, alamofire

I am trying to download some small images, in order.
First, I download a JSON from server and then I parse it into an array of objects.
From that point on, I need to download one image for each object in that array.
Since I tried to do this inside a for loop, DispatchQueue.main.async gets called by array.count times and obviously, I am trying to avoid this.
Can you suggest the best approach?

```
for partner in DataSingleton.sharedInstance.returnPartners()
    {
        let downloadURL: String = ("\(DataSingleton.sharedInstance.returnGetPartnersLogosRoute())/\(partner.logo!)")
        let destination: DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
            var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            documentsURL.appendPathComponent(partner.logo)
            
            return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
        }
                
        AF.download(downloadURL, to: destination).response { response in
            print(response)
            
            switch response.result
            {
                case .success(let json):
                    print("SERVER RESPONSE OK")

                    if( ((response.response?.statusCode)! == 200) ||
                        ((response.response?.statusCode)! == 201) )
                    {
                        print("SERVER RESPONSE OK! Code \(String(describing: response.response?.statusCode))")

                        self.downloadPartnersLogosStatus = true
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("SERVER RESPONSE NOK! Code \(String(describing: response.response?.statusCode))")
                        self.downloadPartnersLogosStatus = false
                    }
                
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("SERVER RESPONSE NOK \(error)")
                    self.downloadPartnersLogosStatus = false
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                if(self.downloadPartnersLogosStatus == true)
                {
                    print("Feedbackul a fost trimis cu succes!")

                    self.downloadPartnersLogosStatus = true
                    completionHandler(self.downloadPartnersLogosStatus)
                }
                else
                {
                    print("NOK ERROR")

                    self.downloadPartnersLogosStatus = false
                    completionHandler(self.downloadPartnersLogosStatus)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `DispatchGroup`, `enter()`, `leave()` and `notify()`? Ie, do multiple async call (like a for loop and your network call), and call a method once all of the calls have finished?

Comment: Do you want to download them sequentially or in parallel?

Comment: @Larme Well, something like that. That for is inside a completionHandler and I need to go back when all images are downloaded. From there, I perform a segue to the next VC.

Comment: @KirilS.To be honest, any would do. I have only 30 images, all of them below 1MB together.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use DispatchGroup to make asynchronous calls within a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652869/how-to-use-dispatchgroup-to-make-asynchronous-calls-within-a-for-loop)